# Multiple subqueries when combined return too many results

Tags: sql

Background

I have merged two long lists of financial transactions (one from each of two companies) into a single table (actually a DataView for reasons not important here).
These two companies did business with lots of customers.
What I want is a query that returns the total number of financial transactions each company had with each customer.

For example:

```
Customer        Company A    Company B

Customer X         10            0
Customer Y         15           26
Customer Z          0           71
```

Hence each customer has dealt with at least one company, and possibly both companies.

So far my query has got this far . . .

```
SELECT v.[Company],
   v. [AnalysisName], 
   s1.CMTtrans,
   s2.CFLtrans
FROM vMainCustTrans AS v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [AnalysisName], COUNT([AnalysisName]) AS CMTtrans
       FROM vMainCustTrans 
       WHERE [Company] = 'Money'
       GROUP BY [AnalysisName]) AS s1
       ON v.[AnalysisName] = s1.[AnalysisName]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [AnalysisName], COUNT([AnalysisName]) AS CFLtrans
       FROM vMainCustTrans 
       WHERE [Company] = 'Forex'
       GROUP BY [AnalysisName]) AS s2
       ON v.[AnalysisName] = s2.[AnalysisName]
ORDER BY v.[Company], v.[AnalysisName]
```

Now sub query (s1) returns 89 customers
sub query (s2) returns 37 customers
Yet the whole query returns 18,989 lines
There should be between 89 and 126 (i.e. 89 + 37) lines, depending on how much overlap there is between Company A and Company B

Could someone kindly point out what is wrong with my query and how I produce the results I want; namely a list of customers, with two counts iro of the number of transactions they have had with each of the two customers.

Comment: Can you provide DD of both table? I mean columns in both table which is needed for the query?

Comment: The output you show crosstabulates the results, but the query doesn't.  It almost sounds like you are trying to get the Cartesian join of the customers and the companies.  That's NumberofCustomers*2 in this case.  Your left joins aren't going to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got it right (Customer = AnalysisName)it should looks like:

```
SELECT 
   v. [AnalysisName], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Company] = 'Money' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CMTtrans,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Company] = 'Forex' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CFLtrans
FROM vMainCustTrans AS v
GROUP BY v.[AnalysisName]
ORDER BY v.[AnalysisName]
```

Comment: Close, but this produces two lines per customer rather than one.  See my table example in the question (Customer Y) did work with both Company A and Company B, but rather than a line for each company, I just want one line with both totals :)